# Reshape a data table

Tags: r

I am using R and have the next table: (example)

```
   ID    Euros          N      Euros        N      Euros        N

1   A    133.911,20     451    134.208,78   450    442,03       328
2   C    9.470,35       2856   26,18        2721   26,28        2699
```

My desired behaviour is that you have Euros in one line and N in other line instead of columns:

```
   ID   Var1     Var2            Var3            Var4

1   A   Euros    133.911,20      134.208,78      442,03 
2   A   N        451             450             328
3   C   Euros    9.470,35        26,18           26,28 
4   C   N        2856            2721            2699
```

I have tried to do so only with A group and using the following code:

```
mydatatable_wide <- spread(mydatatable, Euros, N)
```

But I don't get my expected result. What I get is:

```
    ID  133.911,20   134.208,78      442,03
 
1   A   451          450             328
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
library(tidyverse)
# your data
df <- tribble(
~ID, ~Euros, ~N, ~Euros, ~N, ~Euros, ~N,
"A", 133911.20, 451, 134208.78, 450, 442.03, 328,
"C", 9470.35, 2856, 26.18, 2721, 26.28, 2699)

# make unique colnames
colnames(df) <- make.unique(colnames(df))

df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(Var1="Euros") %>% 
  select(ID, Var1, Var2=Euros, Var3=Euros.1, Var4=Euros.2) 

df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(Var1 = "N") %>% 
  select(ID, Var1, Var2=N, Var3=N.1, Var4=N.2)

newdf <- rbind(df1, df2) %>% 
  arrange(ID)
```

[image]