# How to reshape a data table

Tags: r

I am using R and have the next table: (example)

```
   ID    Euros          N      Euros        N      Euros        N

1   A    133.911,20     451    134.208,78   450    442,03       328
2   C    9.470,35       2856   26,18        2721   26,28        2699
```

My desired behaivour is that you have Euros in one line and N in other line instead of columns:

```
   ID   Var1     Var2            Var3            Var4

1   A   Euros    133.911,20      134.208,78      442,03 
2   A   N        451             450             328
3   C   Euros    9.470,35        26,18           26,28 
4   C   N        2856            2721            2699
```

I have tried to do so only with A group and using the following code:

```
mydatatable_wide <- spread(mydatatable, Euros, N)
```

But I don´t get my expected result. What I get is:

```
    ID  133.911,20   134.208,78      442,03
 
1   A   451          450             328
```

Comment: same comment as in your previous (closed) question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66473278/reshape-a-data-table ): please add sample data... use `dput(mydata)` or the likes of that .. If you don't, you'll probably face another closed question soon.

Answer (score 0):

Need some work to achieve what you want - I am using `dplyr` & `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Here is the tribble from your question
# Note that in my language "." is decimal point and "," is thousand separate
# In R code thousand separate is not used.
df <- tribble(
  ~ID, ~Euros, ~N, ~Euros, ~N, ~Euros, ~N,
  "A", 133911.20, 451, 134208.78, 450, 442.03, 328,
  "C", 9470.35, 2856, 26.18, 2721, 26.28, 2699)

df %>%
  # first convert your data set into a long version with multiple lines per ID
  # contains all the numerical values Euros & N
  pivot_longer(cols = where(is.numeric), names_to = "var", values_to = "value") %>%
  # then split them into multiple group of Euros using group_by & group_map
  group_by(var) %>%
  group_map(~ {
    .x %>% 
      group_by(ID) %>%
      # in group map within each ID create a index var for those values
      mutate(index_name = paste0("var_", seq(1, n(), by =1))) %>%
      # then pivot them wider to have one line per ID & (Euros/N)
      pivot_wider(names_from = "index_name", values_from = value, values_fill = NA)
  }, .keep = TRUE) %>%
  # Finally combined all the data.frame from group_map into one data.frame
  bind_rows()
```

Output

```
  ID    var     var_1    var_2  var_3
  <chr> <chr>   <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A     Euros 133911. 134209.   442. 
2 C     Euros   9470.     26.2   26.3
3 A     N        451     450    328  
4 C     N       2856    2721   2699
```